# How to update quantity in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I want to write a function which updates the quantity in the database. In my code it throws an error "stokModel is null". Why? I cannot reach id in my datagridview rows and stok model returns null. There is my question how can I reach id for each record in xstSabits and update quantity with this id.

Here is my code ;

```
private void StokMiktariGuncelle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvSepet.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        using (fastCellDbEntities db = new fastCellDbEntities())
        {
            var stokModel = db.xstSabits.Find(Convert.ToInt32(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value));

            stokModel.azamiStok -= stokModel.azamiStok - Convert.ToDecimal(dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value);

            db.Entry(stokModel).Property(x => x.azamiStok).CurrentValue = stokModel.azamiStok;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to look at `dgvSepet.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value` to see what's inside it? Maybe you read an Id that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: yes ı have tried it, in this line stokmodel returns null and it cannot access the specific id. Why ?

Comment: Did you check whether your database entity actually uses an integer as primary key? Find will always try to match against the primary key column (first cache than issue a DB statement). Also just to be sure you might want to check if the entity with the Id you read from your DataGrid actually exists in your database.

Comment: my Datagridview columns add with Manuel like dt.Columns.Add["Id"] couse ı want to manage my basket Datagridview parametrically. Okey well, how can ı get id other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems the management of your Ids inside a DataGriView seems a bit tricky.
As you want to set up your columns manually you might want to consider setting up the `DataPropertyName` property of every column. After doing this you can bind your DatabaseModels directly to the Grids DataSource.

This will make it easy to read the Id from selected rows.

Here is a simple example:

```
    CREATE TABLE exampleEntity
    (
        [Id] int not null PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        [SomeValue] int not null,
        [SomeString] varchar(max) null
    );

    INSERT INTO exampleEntity ([SomeValue], [SomeString])
    VALUES
    (42, 'String21ß'),
    (35, 'asdadkpq3eß0i'),
    (37, ''),
    (24, null),
    (17, 'laksjdadjqpwdp')
    ;
```

From this simple database, I scaffolded a code-first from database EF model.

Then simply set up your DataGridView (adding a `DataPropertyName` to each column)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.dt.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dt.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dt.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        //Id column
        this.dt.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            DataPropertyName = "Id", //Name of database column
            Name = "Id", //Display name of datagrid column
            Visible = false
        });

        //SomeValue Column
        this.dt.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            DataPropertyName = "SomeValue",
            Name = "Value"
        });

        //SomeString Column
        this.dt.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            DataPropertyName = "SomeString",
            Name = "String"
        });
    }
```

Then to load your data you can now use DataBinding:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.dt.DataSource = new ExampleModel().exampleEntities.ToList();
```

And now reading the Id from a selected item is pretty easy:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Read id from selected item
        int idSelectedItem = (this.dt.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as exampleEntity).Id;

        using (ExampleModel ctxt = new ExampleModel())
        {
            exampleEntity entity = ctxt.exampleEntities.Find(idSelectedItem);

            entity.SomeValue += 42;

            ctxt.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Important note** You could avoid opening another context when reading the selected item if you reuse the same context used to fill the DataGridView in the first place.